# Difference between "function of positive type" and "positive definite function"

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

Is there a difference between
a) "function of positive type"
b) "positive definite function"
?

(
Background for those who know not what this is about:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function,
In short: a function defining matrix elements of a positive definite matrix
)

Comment: I did not have heard any of these statements, only positive definite matrix/operator. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Positive definite function is standard but some people also say function of positive type for the same concept.